# How can I return Wordpress content with generated ID's based on the number of H2 tags

Tags: replace, foreach

What I'm trying to do it make a code where all H2 tags from `the_content` are pulled and read out to create a table of content. I've done this succesfully with the code below:

```
function h2s_in_the_content($content) {
    if (preg_match_all('#<h2>(.*?)</h2>#', $content, $matches)) {
        foreach ($matches[1] as $key => $value) {
            
            echo '<li class="inhoudsopgave-li">';
            echo '<a href="#' . $key . '" class="link white">' . $value . '</a>';
            echo '</li>';
        }
    }
}

add_filter('the_content', 'h2s_in_the_content', 98);
```

The output is like the picture below where all H2's are pulled and converted to links.
[image: Picture of the table of contents with pulled H2's]

The problem I'm encountering is that I want to fetch `the_content`, read and replace all H2's on the same way as above and return them with the `$key` variable which should output this: `<h2 id="0/1/2/3/etc.">`. I'm using this code to try and do that:

```
function replace_text_wps($content){
    if (preg_match_all('#<h2>(.*?)</h2>#', $content, $matches)) {
        foreach ($matches[1] as $key => $value) {
            $replace = array(
                '<h2>' => '<h2 id="' . $key . '">'
            );
        return $content;
        }
    }
    $content = str_replace(array_keys($replace), $replace, $content);
    return $content;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'replace_text_wps',99);
```

The code is somewhat successful, but the problem is that all H2's are returned with `id="2"` instead of 0/1/2/3/etc. See the image below of the source code.

[image]

What is wrong in my code and how can I make it so that it counts each H2 and returns the id based on the number of the H2 encountered. It works in the first example where the H2's are pulled and changed to links but not in the second example..

Thanks a lot for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do a custom replacement, you could keep track of the number of times the function is triggered, and use [preg_replace_callback](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
$html = <<<HTML
This is <h2>H2 nummer 1</h2>
and this is This is <h2>H2 nummer 2</h2>
This is <h2>H2 nummer 3</h2>
HTML;

function replace_text_wps($content)
{

    return preg_replace_callback('#<h2>(.*?)</h2>#', function ($m) {
        static $h2Count = 0;
        return sprintf('<h2 id="%s">%s</h2>', ++$h2Count, $m[1]);
    }, $content);
}

echo replace_text_wps($html);
```

Output

```
This is <h2 id="1">H2 nummer 1</h2>
and this is This is <h2 id="2">H2 nummer 2</h2>
This is <h2 id="3">H2 nummer 3</h2>
```

See a [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/GOpmB).